# md-autocomplete doesn't work after once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, md-autocomplete

1. I've made a simple auto complete functionality on text search. There are two functions - querySearch(searchText) and homeresults(item). The querySearch function correctly fetches the results and there is no issue there. Once a result is selected by the user, then it calls homeresults function. This function works fine for the first time, but doesn't work after that unless I return to home page. So once a user is on results page, he can't use the search bar again unless he comes back to home page. There are no errors. Here is my code snippet:
2. **HTML**

   ```
   <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
   <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.title" md-delay="400" md-min-length="2" md-floating-label="Search for any Query">
       <div layout-align="start center">
           <span md-highlight-text="searchText" ng-click="homeresult(item)">{{item.title}}</span>
       </div>
       <md-not-found>No matches found </md-not-found>
   </md-autocomplete>
   ```
3. **Javascript**

   ```
    $scope.querySearch = function(search) {
    var key = $scope.searchText;
    console.log('keyword searched by user is ' + key);
    return $http.get('/api/searchresult?title=' + key)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data
        });
    };
    $scope.homeresult = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    $timeout(function() {
        item.title = item.title.replace(/ /g, '-');
        $location.url('/results').search({
            "title": item.title
        })
     }, 50);
    };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the homeresult(), code is redirecting to /results. So, instead of redirection, if you show results on the same page where md-autocomplete is defined, it will work. You can add a simple check to hide the results until we get response from $http.